# Clone project from a google cloud repository as member

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I used A1 google account to create one repository on Google Cloud. And I grant B1 access as reader and writer to this repository.

But now I can't find any way to use B1 account to clone this repository to local. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for bother, I've found that I need to also grant acess to the project to B1, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you well mentioned, you need to **grant** the account with the permissions required to [Clone a repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-a-repository). Based on this, I recommend you to take a look on the [Granting User Access to Repositories and Projects](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access) guide where you can find detailed information about the process of adding these permissions, as well as the [Roles and permissions matrix](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#roles_and_permissions_matrix) document, that contains the available roles when working with **Cloud Source Repositories**.